# sklearn train_test_split - ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2552, 1] /Linear Regression

Tags: scikit-learn

I need assistance reshaping my input to match my output.

I wanted to create a model that vectorizes and classifies 'All information' information so that the label'Fall' can be divided into 0 and 1.
However, I keep getting the [ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2552, 1]] error.
The'shape' looks fine, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
## Linear Regression

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
#instance->fit->predict

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model=LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)

data=pd.read_csv("Fall_test_0826.csv", encoding='cp949', header=0)
data.head(2)


X=data.drop(["fall"], axis=1)

y= data.fall


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state = 0) 


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf_vect=TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_vect.fit(X_train)#단어사전 만듬

X_train_tfidf_vect = tfidf_vect.fit_transform(X_train['All information']).toarray()
X_test_tfidf_vect = tfidf_vect.transform(X_test)

lr_clf=LinearRegression()
lr_clf.fit(X_train_tfidf_vect, y_train)
pred = lr_clf.predict(X_test_tfidf_vect)


from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

print('Logisitic Regression _ {0:.3f}'.format(accuracy_score(y_test, pred)))
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-bec6ead862c8> in <module>
----> 1 print('{0:.3f}'.format(accuracy_score(y_test, pred)))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py in accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize, sample_weight)
    185 
    186     # Compute accuracy for each possible representation
--> 187     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    188     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    189     if y_type.startswith('multilabel'):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     79     y_pred : array or indicator matrix
     80     """
---> 81     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
     82     type_true = type_of_target(y_true)
     83     type_pred = type_of_target(y_pred)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    254     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    255     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 256         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
    257                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    258 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2552, 1]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qljPq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLFHF.png)

Comment: Side note: you only need a `fit` here, `tfidf_vect.fit_transform(X_train['All information']).toarray()`, not a `fit_transform`

Comment: Can you share the shapes of the input dataframes/arrays?

Comment: could you edit your question to show the csv you are using or the shape of both y_test and pred?

Comment: @yatu Yes, I inserted an image. Would you check it?

Comment: @DiegoRueda Of course. I inserted an image related to your advice

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your the lines in your code from

```
X_test_tfidf_vect = tfidf_vect.transform(X_test)
```

to

```
X_test_tfidf_vect = tfidf_vect.transform(X_test['All information'])
```

But your approach is wrong. You are going for Linear Regression but trying to use classifciation metrics (accuracy_score) ([Reference](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#classification-metrics))

Doing so should lead to the error `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets`

So this will not work, because your array `pred` will hold float values, so for example 0.5, but for the accuracy_score you need class labels as integers, so for example 0,1,2 or 3 etc.

You need to use regression metrics instead to evaluate your Linear Regression.

Have a look at the available regression metrics [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#regression-metrics).